# Editing items (string) in Collection (SortedSet) C#

Tags: c#, collections

So I have this `SortedSet<string>`:

```
SortedSet<string> AllWords = new SortedSet<string>();
```

which gets some strings later.
If I can find any char `"B"` in any element of this sorted set-s string, then I want to change it to char `"X"`.
So how can I do this?

Comment: I'm afraid you need to remove and new string with changed chars - because `strings` are immutable and cannot be modified.

Comment: OP, if my answer helped you, please accept it, if not please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a new `SortedSet`, and assign it back to `AllWords`

```
AllWords = new SortedSet<string>(AllWords.Select(s => s.Replace('B', 'X')));
```

using the constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<>` and a bit of LINQ

Comment: no problem!  If the answer fixed your problem, I'd appreciate it if you marked it as correct

Answer (score 1):

i'd say you should get a set and return a new set like so:

```
public SortedSet<string> DoSomething(SortedSet<string> old)
{
   SortedSet<string> newSet = new SortedSet<string>();

   foreach(string curr in old)
     newSet.Add(curr.Replace("B", "X"));

   return newSet;
}
```